# Can't find Python.h header in path

Tags: python

I am trying to compile the source codes for a simulator which uses C++ and Python. However, it gives me this error:

```
Error: can't find Python.h header in ['path-to-my-python/include/python2.6']
Install Python headers (package python-dev on Ubuntu and RedHat)
```

However, I can see that the header file is there and I have set the path to it. How can I fix or diagnosis the problem?

Answer (score 0):

When I google for [Error: can't find Python.h header in](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22Error%3a%20can%27t%20find%20Python.h%20header%20in%22&oq=%22Error%3a%20can%27t%20find%20Python.h%20header%20in%22), the first link takes me to:

http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.emulators.m5.users/10463

Where it looks like back in May, someone had the same exact problem you're having and someone explained how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

is your path-to-my-python a relative path? if so, maybe the compiler/make/builder is trying to go to a different directory and thus can't find it.

What are you using? cmake? SCons? see what the compiler/linker flags are and see where that path is executing from. That will give you an idea.